# Replacing a fragment - New instance of fragment class isn't instantiated

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

I'm trying to replace a fragment with a another fragment with the following lines of code:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = Activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            UploadCompleted ucompleted = new UploadCompleted();
            ft.Replace(Resource.Id.CameraFragmentContainer, ucompleted, "uploadcompleted");
            ft.AddToBackStack(null);
            ft.Commit();
```

The fragment is being replaced inside another fragment which uses the Activity's fragment manager. The issue is that the OnCreate and OnCreateView methods of the replaced fragment aren't invoked and an old instance of fragment (the fragment which was instantiated the first time I replaced it) get's instantiated which is why I'm not able to pass any new values to the replaced fragment. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to android development so my knowledge of fragments isn't that great.

Answer (score 1):

As per your logic,  `OnCreate` and `OnCreateView` of the new Fragment should get invoked.  It is a good practice to do `FragmentTransaction` at `Activity` level rather than,  at Fragment level.  In the above snippet you are creating an instance of the new Fragment from within the already displayed Fragment and replacing itself from the parent Activity.  This is not a recommended approach. I would suggest the following change.

```
public class ParentActivity:Activity 
{
    public void ChangeToUploadCompleted() 
    {
         FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
         UploadCompleted ucompleted = new UploadCompleted();
         ft.Replace(Resource.Id.CameraFragmentContainer, ucompleted, "uploadcompleted");
         ft.AddToBackStack(null);
         ft.Commit(); 
    } 
} 

public FirstFragment:Fragment 
{
    void CaptureCompleted () 
    {
        ((ParentActivity)Activity).ChangeToUploadCompleted();
    } 
}
```

This is the good practice to switch fragments.  This might fix your problem too

Answer (score 0):

```
ft.Replace(Resource.Id.CameraFragmentContainer, ucompleted, "uploadcompleted");
```

In this R.id is the layout that you place in Fragment Activity or Activity and UploadCompleted  is Fragment class which you want to replace so use xml like this in FRagmentActivity or ACtivity class

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

when you want to replace use this

```
FragmentTransaction ft = Activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
UploadCompleted ucompleted = new UploadCompleted();
ft.Replace(Resource.Id.lin, ucompleted, "uploadcompleted");
ft.AddToBackStack(null);
ft.Commit();
```

Comment: this is what I'm actually doing.

Comment: In ft.Replace(Resource.Id.lin, ucompleted, "uploadcompleted"); what is Resource.Id use R.id
ft.Replace(R.Id.lin, ucompleted, "uploadcompleted");

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you meant to say. Are you saying that I should replace Resource.Id by R.Id? I'm building the app with xamarin using C# so the syntax in Xamarin is a bit different from Java.